# Python Using Lamda Function to Attach to Tkinter Button

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to tkinter and lamada function in python. I tried to use multi-thread with tkinter so that my 'update' button would not cause any 'freezing time' to the main GUI. if I use lamda function to attach to a button and spawn a new thread, it works perfectly fine. However, if I use normal function to attach to a button and spawn a new thread, the error prompted out.

Here is my code with the normal function to spawn the thread:

```
from Tkinter import *
import datetime
import datetime as dt
import threading

class Threading(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        output = 'hello world'
        App.text.insert(INSERT, output)

def create_thread(name1):
    a = Threading(name=name1)
    return a

class app():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)       
        self.text = Text(
        master, wrap=WORD, height=20, width = 64, bg='#D9F9FF', 
        highlightbackground=background_color, state= DISABLED, 
        )
        self.text.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=4, rowspan=4, padx=5, pady=20, sticky=E+W+S+N)
        self.update = Button(master, text="Update", command= create_thread('1')).grid(column=0, 
                             columnspan=2, row=8)


def main():
    global App, root
    root=Tk()
    App = app(root)
    root.mainloop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    background_color = "#E3FFE3"
    main()
```

After running this code, the error

```
Exception in thread 1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "f:/Python/Test1.py", line 15, in run
    App.text.insert(INSERT, output)
NameError: global name 'App' is not defined
```

will raise.

if I change the Button(command) to :

```
self.update = Button(master, text="Update", command= lambda: Threading(name='Update')
                     ).grid(column=0, columnspan=2, row=8)
```

It works without any error.

I do not any clue that why this error raise. After reading some documents about normal function and lamda function, I think they can be used interchangablely?

Thank you for your help

Comment: ```command= create_thread('1')``` this runs the function straight away, not when it is clicked. Lambas are run when the button is actually clicked.

Comment: Use lambdas or ```functools.partial``` for tk button callbacks.

Comment: Also, ```tkinter``` isn't thread-safe so you can only modify widgets in the main loop. You can although use tkinters ```after()``` method.

Comment: Thank you so mch, Joshua. That explains why the error raised. For the text wideget modification, I will try to use after() method instead. :)

Comment: use `global App` inside `run(self)`. Also make sure that the `App` variable is defined BEFORE you use `thread.start()`